# Synchronized curl requests

Tags: c++, multithreading, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to do HTTP requests to multiple targets, and I need to them to run (almost) exactly at the same moment.

I'm trying to create a thread for each request, but I don't know why Curl is crashing when doing the perform. I'm using an easy-handle per thread so in theory everything should be ok...

Has anybody had a similar problem? or Does anyone know if the multi interface allows you to choose when to perform all the requests?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of the code:

```
void Clazz::function(std::vector<std::string> urls, const std::string& data)
{
    for (auto it : urls)
    {
        std::thread thread(&Clazz::DoRequest, this, it, data);
        thread->detach();
    }
}

int Clazz::DoRequest(const std::string& url, const std::string& data)
{
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_slist *headers = NULL;

    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Expect:"); 
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data.c_str());

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1L);

    //curlMutex.lock();
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    //curlMutex.unlock();
    long responseCode = 404;
    curl_easy_getinfo (curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &responseCode);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_slist_free_all(headers);
}
```

I hope this can help, thanks!

Comment: Post an example of your code, so we can understand better. cUrl supports multithreading as I know (OS? compiler?)

Comment: Two options for doing this and both should work fine. Either use the multi interface and send both requests in the same thread. Or create two threads and use the easy interface.

Comment: Try to use a mutex when you call cUrl, so you can reduce the ranges of possibilities to a race condition in cUrl (unlucky) or on how you use it (more unlucky ;) )

Comment: Shouldn't need a mutex when calling curl_easy_perform from two different threads.

Comment: I have just edited the question to add the snippet of code. I hope that can help. if I uncomment the locks it works fine, but it gets serialized. I have tried to make copies of both params to avoid the chance of the sting being destroyed before the thread uses it.... but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being able to debug properly in the device y have found that the problem is an old know issue with curl.

http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2010-11/0181.html

after using CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL in every curl handle the crash has disappeared. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `curl_global_init` anywhere? Perhaps rather early in your main() method?

Quoting from http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_global_init.html:

> **This function is not thread safe.** You must not call it when any other thread in the program (i.e. a thread sharing the same memory) is running. This doesn't just mean no other thread that is using libcurl. Because curl_global_init calls functions of other libraries that are similarly thread unsafe, it could conflict with any other thread that uses these other libraries.

Quoting from http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_init.html:

> If you did not already call curl_global_init, curl_easy_init does it automatically. This may be lethal in multi-threaded cases, since curl_global_init is not thread-safe, and it may result in resource problems because there is no corresponding cleanup.

It sounds like you're not calling `curl_global_init`, and letting `curl_easy_init` take care of it for you. Since you're doing it on two threads simultaneously, you're hitting the thread unsafe scenario, with the lethal result that was mentioned.

Comment: I think that's not the case. I'm calling to curl_global_init in the first line of my main function...