# Is libCurl really thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, valgrind, libcurl

After being unable to find out what was happening in my app in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966220/synchronized-curl-requests/30066013), I have tried to reproduce it in my pc using valgrind to find memory / multithread problems. I have seen in many places this:

```
==769== Possible data race during write of size 4 at 0xACD3ADC by thread #13
==769== Locks held: none
==769==    at 0x4C36067: memset (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==769==    by 0x4E4570D: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (allocatestack.c:249)
==769==    by 0x4C30C90: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==769==    by 0x509F957: Curl_thread_create (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)
==769==    by 0x50A261B: Curl_resolver_getaddrinfo (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)
==769==    by 0x5066163: Curl_resolv (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)
==769==    by 0x507D74D: Curl_connect (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)
==769==    by 0x508D62F: multi_runsingle (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)
==769==    by 0x508E180: curl_multi_perform (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)
==769==    by 0x50857B2: curl_easy_perform (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)
==769==    by 0x489D63: ConnectionMgr::checkInternetConnection() (ConnectionMgr.cpp:287)
==769==    by 0x490E9E: void std::_Mem_fn<void (ConnectionMgr::*)()>::operator()<, void>(ConnectionMgr*) const (in /home/user/app)
==769== 
==769== Address 0xACD3ADC is 44 bytes inside a block of size 304 alloc'd
==769==    at 0x4C2DFF0: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==769==    by 0x4012E54: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:296)
==769==    by 0x4E45DA0: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (allocatestack.c:589)
==769==    by 0x4C30C90: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==769==    by 0x509F957: Curl_thread_create (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)
==769==    by 0x50A261B: Curl_resolver_getaddrinfo (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)
==769==    by 0x5066163: Curl_resolv (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)
==769==    by 0x507D74D: Curl_connect (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)
==769==    by 0x508D62F: multi_runsingle (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)
==769==    by 0x508E180: curl_multi_perform (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)
==769==    by 0x50857B2: curl_easy_perform (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0)
==769==    by 0x489D63: ConnectionMgr::checkInternetConnection() (ConnectionMgr.cpp:287)
```

The function I'm running in a separated thread is this one.

```
void ConnectionMgr::checkInternetConnection()
{
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.google.com");
    curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY, 1L);

    long responseCode = 404;
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_getinfo (curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CONNECTCODE, &responseCode);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    mHasInternet = (responseCode == 200);
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you calling `curl_global_init` during your program startup? From [`curl_easy_init` documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_init.html): "If you did not already call `curl_global_init`, `curl_easy_init` does it automatically. This may be lethal in multi-threaded cases, since `curl_global_init` is not thread-safe"

Comment: yeah. It's the first line in the main function, before any thread has been created.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe this question is a bit outdated but I found the answer to it. The problem was that Curl was using signals to notify timeouts on requests and seems not to work fine with multi-threading.

To fix it I used **curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);** and after that it worked properly.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes!**

libcurl is thread-safe under the [documented restrictions](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/threadsafe.html). Hundreds of applications are using it every day successfully in a threaded way.

Are there any bugs? Sure, and we work hard at fixing all of them that we get reported to the project.

Comment: I read the documentation and I'm struggling to get a simple conclusion out of it. Is the correct conclusion that: *everything* is thread safe except for anything that has the word `global`? (thanks for the great library btw)

Comment: I'm sorry but I think [that document](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/threadsafe.html) is very clear (possibly because I wrote most of it). I'd need a more exact and detailed question in order to answer better.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist that is right, the global init & global clean functions are indeed not thread safe. And CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL need to be to `1L` set as well.